# Enabling PDF thumbnail preview on Windows 10 causes PC to slow-freeze temporarily

Tags: windows-10, performance, pdf, adobe-acrobat, thumbnails

I have Acrobat Reader DC Installed on a Windows 10 PC and when I enable PDF file thumbnail preview (via Edit>Preferences) after a while my PC is becoming noticeably slower on the Windows environment-temporary cursor freezing, slow to open any folder etc.

I usually have about 4-5 PDF files on my workspace but removing these did not help, while if I try to open a folder with a multitude of PDF files the process of loading the thumbnail previews is extremely slow-about 5 minutes for a folder of ~20gb.

I run the latest drivers for my VGA (Nvidia 760) and the Acrobat Reader DC is also updated.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue? It might sound trivial but the preview option allows me to find PDF files much faster instead of having to read each description of every individual file on an archive of 100s of files. 
Thanks in advance!